# SystemD JournalD cannot disable child process output

Tags: systemd, systemctl, journalctl, podman, docker-compose

I am running SystemD version 249.7+ on a custom embedded Linux device with Kernel 5.10.50. I am using Podman 4.0.2 with Docker-Compose to run a few containers. The problem I have is that the 'conmon' child processes from the podman system service duplicates every single journald log entry that the docker-compose process produces. I want to remove the conmon version of the log entries, and keep only those produced by docker-compose.

Journalctl shows the duplicate entries like this:

```
-- Journal begins at Sun 2012-01-01 00:02:21 UTC. --
Mar 30 17:06:15 device conmon[1625]: {"products":["Linux","Windows","Mac"]}
Mar 30 17:06:16 device sh[16648]: app1  | App1 endpoint hit ...
Mar 30 17:06:16 device sh[16648]: app3  | {"products":["Linux","Windows","Mac"]}
Mar 30 17:06:16 device sh[16648]: app2  | App2 endpoint hit ...
Mar 30 17:06:16 device sh[16648]: app1  | 10.89.0.3 - - [30/Mar/2022 17:06:15] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
Mar 30 17:06:16 device sh[16648]: app2  | Getting http://app1 ...
Mar 30 17:06:16 device sh[16648]: app2  | Status of GET: 200
Mar 30 17:06:16 device sh[16648]: app2  | Results of GET: {"products":["Linux","Windows","Mac"]}
Mar 30 17:06:16 device sh[16648]: app2  |
Mar 30 17:06:16 device sh[16648]: app2  | 10.89.0.4 - - [30/Mar/2022 17:06:15] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
Mar 30 17:06:21 device conmon[1558]: App2 endpoint hit ...
Mar 30 17:06:21 device conmon[1558]: Getting http://app1 ...
Mar 30 17:06:22 device sh[16648]: app1  | App1 endpoint hit ...
Mar 30 17:06:22 device sh[16648]: app2  | App2 endpoint hit ...
Mar 30 17:06:22 device sh[16648]: app1  | 10.89.0.3 - - [30/Mar/2022 17:06:22] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
Mar 30 17:06:22 device sh[16648]: app3  | {"products":["Linux","Windows","Mac"]}
Mar 30 17:06:22 device sh[16648]: app2  | Getting http://app1 ...
Mar 30 17:06:22 device sh[16648]: app2  | Status of GET: 200
Mar 30 17:06:22 device sh[16648]: app2  | Results of GET: {"products":["Linux","Windows","Mac"]}
Mar 30 17:06:22 device sh[16648]: app2  |
Mar 30 17:06:22 device sh[16648]: app2  | 10.89.0.4 - - [30/Mar/2022 17:06:22] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
Mar 30 17:06:22 device conmon[1393]: App1 endpoint hit ...
Mar 30 17:06:22 device conmon[1393]: 
Mar 30 17:06:22 device conmon[1393]: 10.89.0.3 - - [30/Mar/2022 17:06:22] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
Mar 30 17:06:22 device conmon[1558]: Status of GET: 200
Mar 30 17:06:22 device conmon[1558]: 
Mar 30 17:06:22 device conmon[1558]: Results of GET: {"products":["Linux","Windows","Mac"]}
Mar 30 17:06:22 device conmon[1558]: 
Mar 30 17:06:22 device conmon[1558]: 10.89.0.4 - - [30/Mar/2022 17:06:22] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
Mar 30 17:06:22 device conmon[1625]: {"products":["Linux","Windows","Mac"]}
```

The conmon logs are produced by the 'conmon' child processes of the podman.service.

```
root@device:~# systemctl status podman
● podman.service - Podman API Service
     Loaded: loaded (8;;file://device/lib/systemd/system/podman.service^G/lib/systemd/system/podman.service8;;^G; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Wed 2022-03-30 15:48:55 UTC; 1h 18min ago
TriggeredBy: ● podman.socket
       Docs: 8;;man:podman-system-service(1)^Gman:podman-system-service(1)8;;^G
   Main PID: 515 (podman)
      Tasks: 17 (limit: 495)
     Memory: 11.8M
        CPU: 2min 11.029s
     CGroup: /system.slice/podman.service
             ├─ 515 /usr/bin/podman --log-level=error system service --time=0
             ├─1391 /usr/bin/dnsmasq -u root --conf-file=/run/containers/cni/dnsname/docker-compose_host_internal_net/dnsmasq.conf
             ├─1393 /usr/bin/conmon --api-version 1 -c 6739cff6019d2f7e8f123d6fb02f163ec99ee73d322672c41d81f85d6218c66f -u 6739cff6019d2f7e8f123d6fb02f163ec99ee73d322672c41d81f85d6218c66f -r /usr/bin/crun -b /con>
             ├─1558 /usr/bin/conmon --api-version 1 -c ae34f69196a5d1b332f2f137942d3728c24bb41d06392b13dcfc7296f39b7936 -u ae34f69196a5d1b332f2f137942d3728c24bb41d06392b13dcfc7296f39b7936 -r /usr/bin/crun -b /con>
             └─1625 /usr/bin/conmon --api-version 1 -c b94e032b37a8690f847442ab9cdcf7b78aefab45231098d02c60b5f79e5c3474 -u b94e032b37a8690f847442ab9cdcf7b78aefab45231098d02c60b5f79e5c3474 -r /usr/bin/crun -b /con>

Mar 30 17:07:19 device conmon[1558]: App2 endpoint hit ...
Mar 30 17:07:19 device conmon[1558]: Getting http://app1 ...
Mar 30 17:07:20 device conmon[1393]: App1 endpoint hit ...
Mar 30 17:07:20 device conmon[1393]: 10.89.0.3 - - [30/Mar/2022 17:07:20] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
Mar 30 17:07:20 device conmon[1558]: Status of GET: 200
Mar 30 17:07:20 device conmon[1558]: 
Mar 30 17:07:20 device conmon[1558]: Results of GET: {"products":["Linux","Windows","Mac"]}
Mar 30 17:07:20 device conmon[1558]: 
Mar 30 17:07:20 device conmon[1558]: 10.89.0.4 - - [30/Mar/2022 17:07:20] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
Mar 30 17:07:20 device conmon[1625]: {"products":["Linux","Windows","Mac"]}
```

I have tried redirecting the podman.service StandardOutput and StandardErr in the SystemD service file to null - but the conmon logs still show up with journalctl.

```
root@device:~# cat /lib/systemd/system/podman.service 
[Unit]
Description=Podman API Service
Requires=podman.socket
After=podman.socket
Documentation=man:podman-system-service(1)
StartLimitIntervalSec=0

[Service]
Environment=XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=
CPUWeight=1000
Type=exec
KillMode=process
StandardOutput=null
StandardError=null
Environment=LOGGING="--log-level=error"
#ExecStart=/bin/sh -c "/usr/bin/podman $LOGGING system service --time=0 1>/dev/null 2>/dev/null"
ExecStart=/usr/bin/podman $LOGGING system service --time=0
```

How can I get rid of the conmon log entries? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `LogLevelMax=error`, which simply limits all logging for the unit to log level error or worse. At least for me, this solved a similar issue where a program would spam journalctl with messages. Maybe it also helps in this case, at least in the sense that it would suppress all non-error messages from the child processes.

It is quite self-explainatory, but for more details, check the manual for systemd units, it explains what this does exactly:
https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.exec.html

Comment: Thank you this worked!